# FastAPI EventSourceResponse loss of SEE data

Tags: python, vue.js, fastapi, server-sent-events, openai-api

I'm using FastAPI and sse_starlette.sse's EventSourceResponse to stream the output from chatGPT. While I'm initially receiving the response in the UI ([see.js](https://github.com/mpetazzoni/sse.js)) as I stream the data, I'm encountering a situation where I get the event afterwards, but not the actual data.

Logging the event and event data from UI
[image]

FastAPI Code (Python):

```py
from sse_starlette.sse import EventSourceResponse

@router.post("/stream")
async def chat_stream(chat_msg: ChatMessage, user: CurrentUser = Depends(get_current_user)):
    try:
        return EventSourceResponse(chat_stram_reply_with_history(chat_msg, curr_user=user))
    except ValueError as error:
        log.error(error)
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY, detail=error.args)

async def chat_stram_reply_with_history(chat_msg: chat.ChatMessage, curr_user: user.CurrentUser):
    try:
        response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
            model=chat_msg.model,
            messages=msgs,
            temperature=chat_msg.temperature,
            max_tokens=chat_msg.max_tokens,
            top_p=chat_msg.top_p,
            stream=True,
            user=str(curr_user.sub)
        )
        for chunk in response:
            # print(chunk)
            # chunk_time = datetime.time() - start_time  # calculate the time delay of the chunk
            # log.debug(f"User: {curr_user.preferred_username} | Response: {chunk}")
            collected_chunks.append(chunk)  # save the event response
            choice = chunk['choices'][0]
            chunk_message = choice['delta']  # extract the message
            collected_messages.append(chunk_message)  # save the message
            # print(
            #     f"Message received seconds after request: {chunk_message}")  # print the delay and text
            # full_reply_content = ''.join([m.get('content', '') for m in collected_messages])
            # print(f"Message received seconds after request: {full_reply_content}")  # print the delay and text
            res = {
                "message_id": reply_msg_id_str,
                # "created": chunk['created'],
                "content": chunk_message.get('content', ''),
                "conversation_id": conversation_id_str,
                "parent_message_id": reply_parent_message_id_str,
                "finish_reason": choice['finish_reason']
            }
            log.debug(f"User: {curr_user.preferred_username} | Response: {res}") # Log is printing even though data empty in UI
            yield json.dumps(res)  # json.dumps(chunk)  #
            #await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    except openai.error.APIError as e:
        # Handle API error here, e.g. retry or log
        error_msg = f"OpenAI API returned an API Error: {e}"
    except openai.error.APIConnectionError as e:
        # Handle connection error here
        error_msg = f"Failed to connect to OpenAI API: {e}"
    except openai.error.RateLimitError as e:
        # Handle rate limit error (we recommend using exponential backoff)
        error_msg = f"OpenAI API request exceeded rate limit: {e}"
    except Exception as e:
        error_msg = f"OpenAI API returned an Exception: {e}"
    final_msg = {
       'finish_reason': 'done'
    }
    yield json.dumps(final_msg)
```

UI Code (Vue3):

```js
import { SSE } from 'sse'
const sendMessage = () => {
  const source = new SSE(`${aiUrl}/api/v1/chat/stream`, {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: getToken(),
    },
    method: "POST",
    withCredentials: true,
    payload: JSON.stringify(payload),
  });
  source.addEventListener("message", (e) => {
    console.log("res", e);
    console.log("res", e.data);
    const resp = JSON.parse(e.data || {});
    if (resp.finish_reason === "done") {
      source.close();
    }
  });
  source.stream();
};
```

Please suggest what is happening and how to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: Any luck in achieving this?